# How to reuse changeSets containing view code

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

The problem:

I have several views in a database which is driven by `liquibase` changeSets.

Sometimes I need to recreate those views. Reasons always different:

- Bugs
- Requirement changes
- Underlying table changes

To do this, I just create a new changeLog file and copy-paste all changeSets containing all view code with needed modifications.

When view code changes - its OK - different changelogs contain different view code.

However there are cases when views must be recreated, but view code didn't change at all.

For example, Table `a` and View `b`.

```
create table a(id int primary key);
create view b as select id from a;
```

Later, i decided to change type of `a.id` column to `bigint`

```
alter table a alter id type bigint
```

This change requires view `b` recreation.
So, now i must create new changeSet with **exactly same code** of views as previous changeSets.

Is there any way to avoid this using `liquibase` and `postgresql`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions that come to mind:

**1 (the dirty one)**.

Each Liquibase changeSet has it's own ID. You can open the `databasechangelog` table and remove the records with changeSet IDs you need to rerun.

This way Liquibase will think that these changeSets haven't been run yet and they will be executed again.

**2 (the cleaner one)**.

Liquibase has a nice feature called `contexts` (check [this](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/contexts.html) out). You can add a context to the changeSets that you might need to rerun (say `recreate-view`). And when you actually will need to rerun these changeSets you can always run Liquibase with the chosen `recreate-view`.

And since you will need to *repeat* the execution of these changeSets, you can add `runAlways="true"` (check out [this](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changeset.html) link) to these changeSets. This way they will be executed every time, and by setting the needed `context` you can determine the scope of the changeLog that will be processed by Liquibase.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
<changeSet id="#6" author="hungpv" runOnChange="true" runOrder="last">
    <sqlFile
        endDelimiter="\nGO"
        splitStatements="true" 
        path="db/run-on-change/views/V_LICENSE_PLATE.sql" />
    <rollback>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

Look, we have `runOnChange=true` and `runOrder=last`. That means this `V_LICENSE_PLATE.sql` file will be run every time it has change, after all others changeset ran and completed. In your case, you can use `runAlways=true` instead of runOnChange

For example: you change data type of your column at changeSet #200 (latest) and have following code at changeset #6

```
<changeSet id="#6" author="acc15" runAlways="true" runOrder="last">
    <sqlFile
        endDelimiter="\nGO"
        splitStatements="true" 
        path="db/run-always/views/V_XXX.sql" />
    <rollback>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

After liquibase passed all changeSets (without `runOrder=last`), it will continue execute changeSets with last runOrder and mission completed

P/s: make sure `xsi:schemaLocation` of your db.changelog.xml must contains `http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd`